# Access class parameters through model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What I need is to learn how to access a class' parameter called
`account_id` in its model, if possible:

```
class Employee::TlpsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  ...
  ...

  private
    def tlp_params
      params.require(:tlp).permit(:account_id, :amount, :dividend, :allocation)
    end
```

Here is where I want to be able to access it in the model class:

```
class Tlp < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account

  ## need to access account_id from tlp controller, so that i may find the right account

  coin_price = 
  # calculate tlp()  // funciton///
  def calculate_tlp()
    @amount = coin_price * ase_count
  end
end
```

If you know a better way to access its accounts information, suggestions are kindly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically, you can using self method.

Model class:

```
def self.your_method(id)
  account = Account.find(id)
  # ...
end
```

Controller:

```
Tlp.your_method(account_id)
```

But what exactly do you hope to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: well this is just how the group had it set up already and i was just jumping in to help, but what I'm trying to do is have @amount calculate its self every time a tlp is created, because its like a interest payment to from an owned stock. So what I'm trying to do is gain access to "ase" and coin_price

Comment: which ase is an Account parameter and coin_price is a RatePlan parameter which RatePlan is another subclass of Account

Comment: @Heeb in this case this solution is right for you. Moreover, i think you should create a separate class for this logic.